# Validating a html text input field as a match for any date format

Tags: jquery, regex, date

I have a text input field in which to enter a date. For various reasons, I am not able to use the datepicker. I would like to be able to enter the date in any format e.g d/m/yy or dd/mm/yy or dd/mm/yyyy...etc

Having entered one of these formats and tabbing off I would like the text value (assuming the input is valid) to be set to the entered date in dd/mm/yyyy format. So for example if you hav entered 1/3/14 I would like the text to be set to 01/03/2014.

So far I have got as far as this but it doesn't seem quite right:-

```
          $('.someDate').on("blur", function (event) {

                var dateRegEx = '^(?:(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])[- /.](3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])|(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])[- /.](1[0-2]|0?[1-9]))[- /.](?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}$';
                var day = 0;
                var month = 0;
                var year = 0;
                var matchArray = $(this).val().match(dateRegEx);
                month = matchArray[0];
                day = matchArray[1];
                year = matchArray[2];
//work out what is the year, month, date etc and set the input text to this
    });
```

Any help with this would be very much appreciated

Comment: What and why does it not seem quite right?

Comment: @Simon, If I type in 1/3/14 I am expecting it to come out with 1 for day, 3 for month and 14 for year. Year is always coming out blank - I have tried changing the indexes.

Comment: So you're asking for the correct regex...

Comment: @Simon, I am not great at RegEx so yes that would be ideal. Should be able to do the rest from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provided a working fiddle for your question with a different approach, less complicated in my eyes. First of all I try to get the date seperator. Then I split the date by this date seperator and form a new date. Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2dVwW/

HTML:

```
<input id="date" type="text" value="01.03.15" />
<button id="transform">Transform</button>Date formatted:<span id="dateFormatted"></span>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#transform').click(function () {
    var date = $('#date').val();
    var sepRegEx = '(?:[- /.])';
    var sepArray = date.match(sepRegEx);

    if (!sepArray) {
        alert("Unknown seperator");
        return false;
    }

    var sep = sepArray[0];
    var dateArray = date.split(sep);
    var month = dateArray[0];
    var day = dateArray[1];
    var year = dateArray[2];

    if (month.length == 1) {
        month = '0' + month;
    } else if (month.length != 2) {
        alert("Wrong month format");
        return false;
    }

    if (day.length == 1) {
        day = '0' + day;
    } else if (month.length != 2) {
        alert("Wrong day format");
        return false;
    }

    if (year.length == 2) {
        year = '20' + year;
    } else if (year.length != 4) {
        alert("Wrong year format");
        return false;
    }

    var dateFormatted = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
    $('#dateFormatted').text(dateFormatted);
});
```